# Ruby C Extension on Windows

Tags: c, ruby, windows

I've been practicing with writing C extensions for Ruby. It works perfectly on Ubuntu and even when I tried linking to an third party library in my case I used SDL2 and it worked just fine on Ubuntu. When I'm writing C extensions for Ruby on Windows it compiles just fine I get my .so file and everything no errors. But when I test require like this `ruby -I. -e "require 'gsdl'"` I get an error saying "The specified module could not be found." Why is this how can I get the C extensions to work.
I have Devkit installed and I used Msys and the make that was included in Devkit's bin folder to make the c extention in my project /ext file. My extconf looks like this

```
require "mkmf"
ext_nme = "gsdl"

dir_config(ext_nme,"C:/Users/my_name/gsdl/SDL/include/SDL2","C:/Users/my_name/gsdl/SDL/lib")
have_library("mingw32")
have_library("SDL2main")
have_library("SDL2")
create_makefile(ext_nme)
```

and my C extention looks like this

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include "SDL.h"

void Init_gsdl(VALUE self);

void Init_gsdl(VALUE self){
  SDL_Window* window;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  window = SDL_CreateWindow("Strawberry",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,240,240,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  SDL_Delay(3000);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  puts("Gehirn SDL");
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

[image: This is my directory structure]

Comment: What's the workflow difference between how you compile it on the two platforms?

Comment: Not much really, on Ubuntu I did pretty much the same thing. The only difference was that I wrote a different path to the header files and libs.

Comment: The problem in Windows actually seems to be the have_library parts. I don't think it's actually linking to those libraries. Is there another way to link to libraries?